# LinkedIn API: adAnalyticsV2 with pivot=CREATIVE: projection permission error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am able to call https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2 pivoting on CREATIVE and get a good response without any projection specified. Default response does not contain campaign ids.

I hope to receive campaign ID with each creative element in the response. `campaign` is listed as one of the fields available in the schema for `creative`a so I attempt to specify a projection as following:

`(*,elements(*(*,pivotValue~(campaign))))`

That generates the following error:

`"pivotValue!": {
        "status": 403,
        "message": "not enough permissions to access field campaign for GET /adCreativesV2",
        "serviceErrorCode": 100
      },`

I am able to successfully apply projections on other pivot fields. This, for example, works fine:

`(*,elements(*(*,pivotValue~(status))))`

I am also able to call /adCreativesV2 explicitly and I get a good response, so I appear to have permissions to use use this method despite what the error message says. Incidentally, /adCreativesV2 returns campaign ids by default, but I hope to avoid extra API calls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get campaign id using code below:

```
params = (
    ("q", "analytics"), # Could be 'Analytics' or 'Statistics'
    ("pivot", "CREATIVE"), # Most relavent:: CAMPAIGN - Group results by campaign. CREATIVE - Group results by creative.
    ("dateRange.start.day", "1"),
    ("dateRange.start.month", "1"),
    ("dateRange.start.year", "2021"),
    ("dateRange.end.day", "31"),
    ("dateRange.end.month", "12"),
    ("dateRange.end.year", "2021"),
    ("timeGranularity", "DAILY"),
    ("projection", "(*,elements(*(*,pivotValue~(campaign))))"),
    ("fields", "pivotValue"),
  )
APIResponse = requests.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2", headers=headers, params=params)
print(APIResponse.json()["elements"])
```